# React nested table component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, nested-table, primereact, mui-datatable

I want to build nested table in my current POC but my parent and child table header and data are different. As I new to React I was not able to build on own. Is there any UI component or Library which can suffice my requirement? 
I have explore PrimeReact and MaterialUI but not address my requirement so please suggest if any.[image]

Comment: with react-table you can make nested tables

Comment: I don't see this as a nested table, but multiple stacked tables. Each row of your initial table could be it's own table with a single row. Then you could insert a separate table after that row when you expand it.

Comment: I tried inserting table , faced lot of issues while updating child row, validating, binding back. So i thought to use any component if its available

Comment: What do you mean by a nested table? If there is an example or something that would be helpful.

Comment: @UladzislauUlasenka please provide an example